# Create a dictionary from list of dictionaries selecting specific values

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a list of dictionaries as below and I'd like to create a dictionary to store specific data from the list.

```py
test_list = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'colour':'Red',
        'name':'Apple',
        'edible': True,
        'price':100
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'colour':'Blue',
        'name':'Blueberry',
        'edible': True,
        'price':200
    },
    {
        'id':3,
        'colour':'Yellow',
        'name':'Crayon',
        'edible': False,
        'price':300
    }
]
```

For instance, a new dictionary to store just the {id, name, price} of the various items.

I created several lists:

```py
id_list = []
name_list = []
price_list = []
```

Then I added the data I want to each list:

```py
for n in test_list:
   id_list.append(n['id']
   name_list.append(n['name']
   price_list.append(n['price']
```

But I can't figure out how to create a dictionary (or a more appropriate structure?) to store the data in the {id, name, price} format I'd like. Appreciate help!

Comment: Have you considered a pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: It would help if you explicitly showed the format you would like.

Comment: How is the `csv` tag relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have too much data, you can use this nested list/dictionary comprehension:

```
keys = ['id', 'name', 'price']
result = {k: [x[k] for x in test_list] for k in keys}
```

That'll give you:

```json
{
  'id': [1, 2, 3],
  'name': ['Apple', 'Blueberry', 'Crayon'],
  'price': [100, 200, 300]
}
```

Comment: `keys = ['id', 'name', 'price']`

Comment: @MYousefi that's correct

Answer (score 1):

I think a list of dictionaries is stille the right data format, so this:

```
test_list = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'colour':'Red',
        'name':'Apple',
        'edible': True,
        'price':100
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'colour':'Blue',
        'name':'Blueberry',
        'edible': True,
        'price':200
    },
    {
        'id':3,
        'colour':'Yellow',
        'name':'Crayon',
        'edible': False,
        'price':300
    }
]

keys = ['id', 'name', 'price']
limited = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in keys} for d in test_list]

print(limited)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Apple', 'price': 100}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Blueberry', 'price': 200}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Crayon', 'price': 300}]
```

This is nice, because you can access its parts like `limited[1]['price']`.

However, your use case is perfect for `pandas`, if you don't mind using a third party library:

```
import pandas as pd

test_list = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'colour':'Red',
        'name':'Apple',
        'edible': True,
        'price':100
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'colour':'Blue',
        'name':'Blueberry',
        'edible': True,
        'price':200
    },
    {
        'id':3,
        'colour':'Yellow',
        'name':'Crayon',
        'edible': False,
        'price':300
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(test_list)

print(df['price'][1])
print(df)
```

The DataFrame is perfect for this stuff and selecting just the columns you need:

```
keys = ['id', 'name', 'price']
df_limited = df[keys]
print(df_limited)
```

The reason I'd prefer either to a dictionary of lists is that manipulating the dictionary of lists will get complicated and error prone and accessing a single record means accessing three separate lists - there's not a lot of advantages to that approach except maybe that some operations on lists will be faster, if you access a single attribute more often. But in that case, `pandas` wins handily.

In the comments you asked "Let's say I had `item_names = ['Apple', 'Teddy', 'Crayon']` and I wanted to check if one of those item names was in the `df_limited` variable or I guess the `df_limited['name']` - is there a way to do that, and if it is then print say the price, or manipulate the price?"

There's many ways of course, I recommend looking into some online `pandas` tutorials, because it's a very popular library and there's excellent documentation and teaching materials online.

However, just to show how easy it would be in both cases, retrieving the matching objects or just the prices for them:

```
item_names = ['Apple', 'Teddy', 'Crayon']

items = [d for d in test_list if d['name'] in item_names]
print(items)
item_prices = [d['price'] for d in test_list if d['name'] in item_names]
print(item_prices)

items = df[df['name'].isin(item_names)]
print(items)
item_prices = df[df['name'].isin(item_names)]['price']
print(item_prices)
```

Results:

```
[{'id': 1, 'colour': 'Red', 'name': 'Apple', 'edible': True, 'price': 100}, {'id': 3, 'colour': 'Yellow', 'name': 'Crayon', 'edible': False, 'price': 300}]
[100, 300]

   id    name  price
0   1   Apple    100
2   3  Crayon    300
0    100
2    300
```

In the example with the dataframe there's a few things to note. They are using `.isin()` since using in won't work in the fancy way dataframes allow you to select data `df[<some condition on df using df>]`, but there's fast and easy to use alternatives for all standard operations in `pandas`. More importantly, you can just do the work on the original `df` - it already has everything you need in there.

And let's say you wanted to double the prices for these products:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin(item_names), 'price'] *= 2
```

This uses `.loc` for technical reasons (you can't modify just any view of a dataframe), but that's way too much to get into in this answer - you'll learn looking into `pandas`. It's pretty clean and simple though, I'm sure you agree. (you could use `.loc` for the previous example as well)

In this trivial example, both run instantly, but you'll find that `pandas` performs better for very large datasets. Also, try writing the same examples using the method you requested (as provided in the accepted answer) and you'll find that it's not as elegant, unless you start by zipping everything together again:

```
item_prices = [p for i, n, p in zip(result.values()) if n in item_names]
```

Getting out a result that has the same structure as `result` is way more trickier with more zipping and unpacking involved, or requires you to go over the lists twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Grismar!

This works really well and looks great! Will study the pandas library a bit more as first time I've seen it.

Let's say I had `item_names = ['Apple', 'Teddy', 'Crayon']` and I wanted to check if one of those item names was in the `df_limited` variable or I guess the `df_limited['name']` - is there a way to do that, and if it is then print say the `price`, or manipulate the price?

Comment: I added some examples to that effect - but I recommend you look into the library before asking more, it's really well documented and there's tons of tutorials online, since it's one of Python's most used third party libraries for science and engineering. I do recommend trying to do the same I did using the accepted answer - see how you like each solution in that scenario.